# what is the way to child element not inherit parents property?

Tags: css, inheritance

what is the way to child element not inherit parents property?
I know way to child element declare individually property.
I curious that people use another way.

Comment: Do you have on example of your code? or maybe a better explanation for what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can either set some styles only for that element:

`p{ color:red; }`

or overwrite the default inherited styles (like `margin` in this case):

`p{ margin: 0; }`

or, in some contexts add a `class` or an `id` to add more weight to the selector (adding an id to the `p`):

```
div p{ color: blue; }
#myParagraph{ color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way

```
div{
  padding:10px;
}

div *{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

But its highly `NOT RECOMMENDED` for elements with many children